# Active virtualenv stopped working in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have noticed that my activate virtual environment stopped working in the VS Code terminal.

My settings.json looks like this:

```
{
 "python.unitTest.unittestArgs": [
    "-v",
    "-s",
    "./documenttagging/tests",
    "-p",
    "test_*.py"
],
"python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": false,
"python.unitTest.nosetestsEnabled": false,
"python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": true,
"python.pythonPath": "env\\Scripts\\python.exe",
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
}
```

Previously my virtualenv was activated automatically and worked fine. It looks like it gets activated in the terminal now as well, but when running pip list I see that it is the system Python installation that is used.

When trying to manually activate the environment in the VS Code terminal by running:

```
env/Scripts/activate
```

I expect the environment to be activated. But when running "pip list" it is clear that it is using the system installation of Python. When I run the same command in a cmd terminal it works fine, and "pip list" shows that the correct environment is activated with the correct packages.

It used to be working fine, but all of a sudden stoppped working

Note: When I run debugger in vscode the correct environment is selected and executed.

My setup:

- OS:Windows 10
- vscode: 1.33.1
- Python: 3.6.8

Any idea what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: I am suddenly having this problem, worked fine then one day pylance started shouting about missing imports and it appeared pip install wont install to the venv for some reason. Ever find the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/env/Scripts/python.exe"
```

or

```
"python.pythonPath": "c:\\your\\entire\\path\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe"
```

Comment: Still have the same issue

Comment: how did you give your `python.pythonPath`

Comment: by setting it insettings.json. I tried both alternatives

Answer (score -1):

You can activate with this command

```
source env/Scripts/activate
```